# Java MySQL dump including stored procedures and functions without using mysqldump

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, database-backups, mysql-backup

My Java application needs to be able to run on a remote system without the MySQL cli installed on it and can only interface with the MySQL database using a MySQL connection ( no ssh ).  I can't use mysqldump.  I can't use mysqldbcopy.

Is there a way to perform a backup of the database under these constraints that contains the Stored Procedures and Functions?  Or can I go back to my supervisor and inform them that they are asking me to do something that's impossible?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that your supervisor is expecting you to perform this task using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`...

Comment: Ok, using `select *  from information_schema.routines` gives me 95% of what I would need to peice something together, however it's missing the data from the create statement.  I have "ROUTINE_DEFINITION" which starts at the "BEGIN" section of my stored procedure code, but how do I get the create portion?

Comment: Combine with `information_schema.parameters`.